# how to convert long int to char

Tags: winapi

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


HANDLE hPort = CreateFile("COM2",
GENERIC_WRITE|GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
DCB dcb;

bool writebyte(char*data)
{
    DWORD byteswritten;
    if (!GetCommState(hPort,&dcb))
    {
        printf("\nSerial port can't be open\n");
        return false;
    }

    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

    if (!SetCommState(hPort,&dcb))
        return false;

    bool retVal = WriteFile(hPort,data,1,&byteswritten,NULL);

    return retVal;
}

int ReadByte()
{

    int Val;
    BYTE Byte;
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
    DWORD dwCommModemStatus;
    if (!GetCommState(hPort,&dcb))
    return 0;

    SetCommMask(hPort,EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR);
    WaitCommEvent (hPort,&dwCommModemStatus,0);
    if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_RXCHAR)
    ReadFile (hPort,&Byte,1,&dwBytesTransferred,0);
    Val = Byte;
    return Val;
}

int main() {

    POINT p;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;


    while(0==0){
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
    HDC hDC;

    hDC = GetDC(NULL);

    cin >> z;
    cout << GetPixel(hDC, x, y) << endl;
    Sleep(z);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);

    char data = GetPixel(hDC, x, y);
        if (writebyte(&data))
        cout <<" DATA SENT.. " << (int)data<< "\n";

    }
}
```

in the part of sending data through serial communication, instead of sending the data as GetPixel(hDC, x, y), it only sends the value "-1" . I was thinking it is because char is only for small integers and the output I was giving is a very very long number. I tried to change it to long int but i still get the same result. That it only sends "-1". I thought that the solution might be converting char to long int or long int to char before sending the data but I don't know how..can someone help me?

Comment: GetPixel returns a COLORREF, don't pretend it's a char. What were you expecting to happen when you try to send a large integer as a single byte?

Comment: And since COLORREF is 4 bytes, you need to call writebyte 4 times to send it.

Comment: @wipw Probably preferable to rewrite writebyte so that it can send more than one byte

Answer (score 7):

Why do you use `hDC` after releasing it?

```
ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
char data = GetPixel(hDC, x, y);
```

`GetPixel` will return -1 (`CLR_INVALID`) in case of an error (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144909(v=vs.85).aspx)).

And, by the way, a `COLORREF` is not a `char`, so you lose Information when storing the return value of `GetPixel` in `char data`. You should store the complete `COLORREF` and send/receive all of it's bytes (so send/receive `sizeof(COLORREF)` bytes).

Also be aware of byte order. If you are transferring multi byte data between two machines then you must assure that both agree on the order of the bytes. If for example one machine is little endian and the other big endian, then they store `COLORREF` with different byte order in memory. One is storing the COLORREF 0x00BBGGRR in memory as `{ 0, 0xbb, 0xgg, 0xrr }` whereas the other is storing it as `{ 0xrr, 0xgg, 0xbb, 0 }`. So you need to define a transmit byte order which both sides use independant of their host byte order. If you don't want to invent the wheel new, you can take a look at network byte order and reuse that. Socket API gives you some functions like `ntohl` and `htonl` which help you in converting from host byte order to network byte order and vice versa.

Comment: now that I've reviewed the code, I  was thinking I am really stupid to even ask this question..haha..anyways, thanks guys..

Comment: @user2201682 Don't we all know these situations when you don't see the obvious (bug)? :-) If you tested my suggestion(s) and think my post is answering your question, then please accept it.